# Why Postfix on Linux require a "-" character before the pathname of the log file?

Tags: linux, postfix, logging, configuration, rsyslog

I´ve found the following [here](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#syslog_howto):

> IMPORTANT: on Linux you need to put a "-" character before the pathname, e.g., -/var/log/maillog, otherwise the syslogd process will use more system resources than Postfix.

But the documentation does not give any reason for that. So, why this "-" is needed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is only required if you still use syslogd or older rsyslog versions

from http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v3compatibility.html , section "Output File Syncing "

> Rsyslogd tries to keep as compatible to stock
>   syslogd as possible. As such, it retained stock syslogd's default of
>   syncing every file write if not specified otherwise (by placing a dash
>   in front of the output file name). While this was a useful feature in
>   past days where hardware was much less reliable and UPS seldom, this
>   no longer is useful in today's worl. Instead, the syncing is a high
>   performace hit. With it, rsyslogd writes files around 50 *times*
>   slower than without it. It also affects overall system performance due
>   to the high IO activity. In rsyslog v3, syncing has been turned off by
>   default. This is done via a specific configuration directive
>   "$ActionFileEnableSync on/off" which is off by default. So even if
>   rsyslogd finds sync selector lines, it ignores them by default. In
>   order to enable file syncing, the administrator must specify
>   "$ActionFileEnableSync on" at the top of rsyslog.conf. This ensures
>   that syncing only happens in some installations where the
>   administrator actually wanted that (performance-intense) feature. In
>   the fast majority of cases (if not all), this dramatically increases
>   rsyslogd performance without any negative effects.